# PHP when sending no image to the form

Tags: php

So I have some forms, that accept image. However, I must have not understood something.
Basically, when an image is selected I want it to be checked and later on uploaded. If no image is selected, I don't care since it is not required.

However, if no image is selected to upload, the image is still checked etc, and the echo never happens. What is going on?

```
        if(isset($_FILES["fileToUpload"]))
        {
            $target_file = $_FILES["fileToUpload"];
            include ('../config/imageCheck.php');
        }
        else
        {
            echo "no image";
        }
```

P.S. I've been working on this college project the last 5 days nonstop, sorry if my question is not the best! :)

Comment: add a simple `if($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'] == "") {echo 'No Image'}` or `if(empty($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'])) {}` whichever suits you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `is_uploaded_file()` function to check whether a file has been uploaded or not, so your code should be like this:

```
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'])){
    // A file has been uploaded
    $target_file = $_FILES["fileToUpload"];
    include ('../config/imageCheck.php');
}else{
    // User hasn't uploaded any file
    echo "no image";
}
```

Or better, use `file_exists()` function in conjunction with `is_uploaded_file()`, like this:

```
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']) && file_exists($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'])){
    // A file has been uploaded
}else{
    // User hasn't uploaded any file
}
```

Here are the references:

- [`is_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php)
- [`file_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what on the other side of this code is happening but if you have a form with image upload element, than probably it returns "false" if image is not selected. In such case your "isset" function will receive a response "false" or "0" and isset will be true because "false" or "0" is also a value.

Maybe you should modify your code to:

```
if($_FILES["fileToUpload"])
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation (["Error Messages Explained"](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)) `$_FILES["fileToUpload"]['error']` will have the value 4 if no file was uploaded.

```
if( $_FILES['picture']['error'] != 4 ) {
    echo "Do stuff...";
} else {
    echo "No image";
}
```